# duplicate variable error on dynamically initializing multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a multidimensional array in c++ using the new operator, however I am getting a duplicate variable error  . I am using xcode compiler on mac.

```
class C_MagicSquares 
{
    public:
        void get_input();
        void print_intro();
        void create_matrix();
        void print_matrix();
        void add_totals();
        void exit_program();
    private:

        int input;

        int **m;
        m=new int*[input];//duplicate variable error;c++requires type specifier for all declarations

        int row;
        int col;

};
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector`  ?

Comment: `m=new int*[input];` should be called inside a function. And yes, rather use  a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Answer (score 0):

`int** m = new int*[input];` should inside a function definition.

You can dynamically create multidimensional array using

```
int** m = new int*[input];
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    m[i] = new int[col];
```

A better approach to use `std::vector` for 2-d array.

You can create 2-D array using `std::vector` like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> m;`